# jQuery: How to refer to element being operated upon?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have following jQuery line where I am trying to change the "id" of the element after cloning the row of a table. How can I refer to the instance of the element and pass it to "buildControlId" function.

```
$row.find("select [id$='ctlType']").attr("id", buildControlId(???));
```

I could do it like this, but I am looking for shorter version without needing to declare variable.

```
var $el = $row.find("select [id$='ctlType']");
$el.attr("id", buildControlId($el[0]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a function as the second parameter:

```
$row.find("select [id$='ctlType']").attr("id", function(){
    buildControlId($(this));
});
```

And your function would return the value for the attribute:

```
function buildControlId($param){
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: Ahh so if I use function then "this" gives me the element. I was trying without function, just using this, but that was giving me element to which 'click' event was bound too.

Comment: Yeah, `this` is dead useful in that respect. You'll notice that @noah did this same in his `each()` answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$row.find("select [id$='ctlType']").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("id", buildControlId(this));
});
```

This way also has the advantage of working on multiple elements. Consider changing your selector to select multiple elements (if that makes sense).